Error Compiling Binutils for i386-elf on macOS: Malformed Archives
I’m trying to cross-compile binutils for i386-elf on macOS (Sequoia 15.0.1, arm64) but encounter an error when running make. Here are the steps I followed:

Installed required dependencies:
brew install gmp mpfr libmpc texinfo


Downloaded and extracted binutils 2.41:
mkdir -p ~/src
cd ~/src
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.41.tar.gz
tar -xzf binutils-2.41.tar.gz


Created a build directory:
mkdir build-binutils
cd build-binutils


Set environment variables:
export CC=gcc
export CXX=g++
export AR=llvm-ar


Configured binutils:
../binutils-2.41/configure \
  --target=i386-elf \
  --prefix=/usr/local/cross \
  --disable-nls \
  --disable-werror


Ran make while compiling the libbfd.la target and encountered the following error:


llvm-ar: error: truncated or malformed archive (terminator characters in archive member "\000\000" not the correct "`\n" values for the archive member header for 0     0     644)
make[4]: *** [libbfd.la] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-bfd] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Before that I only get source code related warnings.
What I've tried
I tried:

Compiling a different version of binutils.
Using a different version of both gcc and clang.
Redownloading all dependencies and different versions of them.
Configuring and making it with expor AR=ar (the following error occurs):

checking whether gcc supports -Wold-style-definition... ld: multiple errors: archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/viliamholly/src/binutils-build/libiberty/libiberty.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/viliamholly/src/binutils-build/zlib/libz.a'; archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/viliamholly/src/binutils-build/bfd/.libs/libbfd.a'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

System Info

macOS Sequoia 15.0.1 (arm64)

Edit
I exported CC as the homebrew version and now I'm getting an error during the configure stage saying that g++ failed sanity check

I think the 4GB limit is probably a red herring. I don't think anything in binutils is even close to that large.

Show more of the output.

@EugeneSh I don't know if that'll help, but that's the full output.

Well.. this one isn't very helpful.. doesn't it have anything before this error?

@EugeneSh not really, only a buch of warnings when it compiles the source code. There are too many to provide all of them.

Does the output include the exact command it uses for the llvm-ar step? Or the path to the executable?

@Kevin only the path to the executable. The output I provided was copy-pasted as is. I will update the question to also contain the output for AR=ar shortly, this outputs more info.
